# Looking for example of infinite integral, but finite body of rotation

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I just happened to remember a question I saw on here probably $1$+ year ago. 
The question asked about intuition about a specific integral ($0 \to \infty$), which turned out to diverge. On the other hand the rotation of the exact same function (inside the integral) turned out to be finite.

I'd really like to read the question and answers again, but I can't find the specific question. Does anybody have a clue, which question I could search for?

Answer (score 2):

You might have been thinking of [Gabriel's Horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn), which is a solid of finite volume but infinite surface area. It's also the solid of revolution of a function whose indefinite integral is infinite.

Comment: I saw a video of Gabriel's Horn in a Numberphile video. It's called *Infinity Paradoxes*.